# How to concatenate string correctly?

Tags: string, scala

I wrote the following simple program

```
object Main extends App {
    println(new MyClass toString)
}

class MyClass {
    var pairs: Map[String, String] = Map[String, String](
       "key1" -> "value1", 
       "key2" -> "value2", 
       "key3" -> "value3"
    )
    val Separator = "separator"

    override def toString = {
        pairs map { case (key, value) => s"$key=$value" } mkString(" ") + Separator
    }
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/aXOFJ9)

I thought the program would print `key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3 separator`. But it does noy. Instead, it prints:

```
key1=value1 separatorkey2=value2 separatorkey3=value3
```

Why? I thought I built string representation of the map first and then add `separator` to the representation.

Comment: Apparently `mkString` takes precedence over `+`, which is a bit weird but understandable. Make them explicit method calls or wrap them in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

One Very Serious Advice :: Although Scala allows you to write code in a more english like way, `list map { case a => a toString }` instead of `list.map({ case a => a.toString })`, do that only when it is not ambiguous.

Or I will even say do not do that at all. You are writing code not poetry.

Here your problems is due to not using parenthesis properly and scala misunderstood your intentions.

```
// this line of yours
pairs map { case (key, value) => s"$key=$value" } mkString(" ") + Separator

//is understood by Scala as
(pairs map { case (key, value) => s"$key=$value" }) mkString " " + Separator
```

Remember that `list.mkString(" " + "ABC")` can also be written as `list.mkString " " + "ABC"` in poetry type Scala.

```
// so... if you want your result then better write things clearly with parenthesis
((pairs map { case (key, value) => s"$key=$value" }) mkString(" ")) + Separator

// Or just stop writing poetry and start writing code
(pairs.map({ case (key, value) => s"$key=$value" }).mkString(" ")) + Separator
```

Comment: But beautiful code is better code! :-P Your sentiment sounds like "real code" wuld need to be hard to read

Comment: The concluding "code" (not "poetry") line has 2 extra/unneeded pairs of `()`.

Comment: No it does not. Any `list.mkString("ab") + "cd"` can be made ambiguous for Scala as `list.mkString ("ab") + "cd"` which will be parsed as list.mkstring(("ab") + "cd"). Also... Even from a readers perspective, for a long statement like this, parenthesis makes more readable code.

Comment: The extra parens are `pairs.map { case _ => }`. Arg to an apply can always be a block expr. I don't follow the prev comment about adding a space. But I agree about not going overboard with infix ops. Dots have low carbon footprint, so should be used guilt-free.

Comment: The thing is I have seen Scala compiler getting confused with complex code involving the use of many Scala syntactic sugar features including  `func BlockExpr` in few cases. So... I have taken a lesson to write as explicit and clear code as possible.